# How to run a coroutine in async.run_until_completed in an async function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

here is the problem:

```
async def init():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main(sessions, message))

async def main(sessions, message):
    # some code to execute...
```

i'am trying to run the function `main(sessions, message)` in `run_until_complete`, but the problem is that I cannot get the `coroutine` in an `async` function, because is it throws an error that: `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'main' was never awaited`

can you tell me please how should i run a function like that correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to use `run_until_complete` inside a coroutine. The way you wait for something to finish inside a coroutine is to await it.

```
async def init():
    await main(sessions, message)
```

Comment: i've tried to use asyncio, because the await sometimes hangs in a program without any errors, and thats why i wanted to use asyncio in some functions, but as i see its not possible

Comment: await doesn’t just hang. It waits for something to finish. You have something somewhere that isn’t completing. You’ll need to provide a lot more details, though, for us to help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
import asyncio

async def init():
    await main(...)

async def main(sessions, message):
    ...

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(init())
```